# gplus authenticate a client-side user before submitting to my web app

Tags: php, google-plus, client-side

This is more of a procedure question question than a code fault one so please be kind if I have posted in the wrong place.

I have successfully authenticated a gplus user client-side so the browser is holding the google id ready for me to use. I now want to post some data to my website with that id as the user id but i want to protect it meaning I don't want just anyone with someone else's gplus id to be able to post to my web app (it has to be the authenticated user at that time).

Should I install the php serverside sdk and use that? If so how do i merge the client-side data with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right about wanting to get the ID in a secure manner to make it hard to impersonate. There are two main options, both properties of the authResult object that comes back to the sign in callback:

1. Send the 'code' to the server. This is part of the OAuth 2.0 flow, and can be exchanged on the server side for an access token. From that you can make API calls as the user, and retrieve the user ID and other details. You can be confident who the user is, as only Google could have generated that code. This would involve using one of the client libraries to handle the token exchange.
2. Use the `id_token`. This is a base64 encoded blob of JSON which includes the user ID (and email address if you requested the 'email' scope). What makes it secure is that it includes a cryptographic signature, which the server can verify, so it cannot be created by someone other than Google. The id token can be used to get the user ID, and so can be used for looking up the user on the server, but doesn't give access to make API calls. The benefit is that it only requires up to date certificates for verification which don't change that often, so most calls require no further network traffic from the server to verify the user.

Which you use is up to you, but both will require some code on the server. In general, if you don't need to call any Google APIs from the server, or are concerned about maximum login performance then use the `id_token`. There's a bit more about that sort of architecture here: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/11/client-server-authentication-with-id.html

You can even combine the two. The first time a user signs in (when they see the consent screen) the code exchange will return not just an access token (for making calls), but also a long-lived refresh token, which you can store securely in a database. If you store that, you can use the `id_token` to look up the user quickly, but still use the refresh token to help with API access.

Comment: I think I am going with option 1 but I could do with a bit more verbose info. If I install the PHP SDK on my server, do I send my request from the browser to my server, authenticate with google there and (if successful) post the data to my db?